# crystal reports without install vs 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

On my laptop I use Visual Studio 2010 and Crystal reports, but when I moved my application to another PC without Visual studio installed, my application got error:

"`CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception`".

I copied Crystal reports dll and add reference and path inside my app but I got same error.

Then I tried install Crystal reports on the PC but got error:

"`you must already have visual studio 2010 installed to proceed with this installation`".

How do I install Crystal reports on the PC without installing Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 0):

download crystal report for runtime to be installed on client PC, you wont need to install crystal report and visual studio try it here 
for 32bit http://www.4shared.com/rar/3MOtCA7w/crforvs_redist_install_32bit_1.html, and look for other site if it is 64 bit.

filename for 32 bit= CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_2.msi; for 64 bit CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_2.msi, that solved my problem when deploying my applicatyion to client pc.

Comment: my pc is 64 bit, what should I install? @odlan yer

Comment: i dont remenber what site i downloaded it but the file is CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_2.msi, try to google where to download it.

Comment: crforvs_redist_install_64bit_1 or CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_2.msi? @odlan yer

Comment: CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_2.msi

Comment: still error `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception` when i check diferent between my laptop and the pc , my laptop have a **C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet**, but in my pc when install runtime only, win32_x86\dotnet cant found. @odlan yer

Comment: and i try to install CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_2.msi , and CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_4.msi . but same error